# Core Data: Passing a managed object to a class

Tags: core-data, properties

I have an app that stores product data in Core Data. I have a popover controller where you select a client, it calls back to the root view controller through Notification Center and then root vc gets that clients purchase agreement from core data. We store it as a property of the vc (workingPA).

That purchase agreement data is then displayed. We have a calculator class (subclass of NSObject) and when the user makes edits to the PA it fires up and runs a bunch of calculations, getting base figures from the PA managed object we retrieved from Core Data. We're passing the PA to the calculator class from the root vc like so:

calculator.workingPA = self.workingPA

My question is this an acceptable way to pass a Core Data object to another class or is there another, "best practice" to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes that's perfectly acceptable.  In Apple's master/detail sample applications that's how the selected object gets passed to the detailView from the masterView.  The detailView can then update the object and save the managedObjectContext.  Just make sure you dereference the object properly if it gets deleted.  You will get some strange stuff if you delete the object from Core Data and then try and access a retained object on the view.  Best to then do something like `calculator.workingPA = nil` and in the calculator check for nil before doing anything.

Comment: Duncan, thanks for the reply. Not sure if I follow on the dereference part - do you mean when we are done using workingPA in the calc class or in root vc after it's been passed - like so calculator.workingPA = self.workingPA; [calculator doStuff]; calculator.workingPA = nil;

Comment: The issue will only arise if you use the `[NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:]` API to delete the `workingPA` and then for some reason go back to the `calculatorView` without having reset the `workingPA` and try and access the now deleted `workingPA` object using the previous reference still stored in the calculator.  Your reference will still be valid but you will get an exception when trying to access the objects properties because it has been deleted and the objects MOC would have been set to nil.

Comment: OK, thanks - we do delete it but that's only when we are syncing with the backend and that happens before it's passed to calculator. We're getting weird behavior where the user is updating the PA but the changes are not being displayed - and it's not consistent, sometimes it works fine. I'll have to keep digging.